# NumPy Slicing HackerRank

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have wrote a function named `array_slice` which gets four numbers `n`, `n_dim`, `n_row`, `n_col` from the user and performs array operations given below.

**Instructions:**

1. Create an array `x` of shape `(n_dim, n_row, n_col)`, having first n natural numbers.
2. Create a Boolean array `b` of shape `(2,)`.
3. Print the values for following expressions: `x[b]` and `x[b,:,1:3]`

For example if we have input `30, 2, 3, 5`, for each corresponding parameters `n`, `n_dim`, `n_row`, `n_col`, Then the output prints will be as:

```
[[[ 0 1 2 3 4] [ 5 6 7 8 9] [10 11 12 13 14]]]
[[[ 1 2] [ 6 7] [11 12]]]
```

The written code is:

```
import numpy as np

# Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT
def array_slice(n,n_dim,n_row,n_col):
    x=np.array(n, dtype=int,  ndmin=n_dim).reshape(n_row,n_col)
    b=np.array([True,False],dtype="bool",ndmin=n_dim).reshape(2,)
    print(x[b])
    print(x[b,:,1:3])


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        n = int(input())
        n_dim = int(input())
        n_row = int(input())
        n_col = int(input())
        array_slice(n,n_dim,n_row,n_col)
```

I went through official documentation NumPy, but still couldn't understand the error. I tried all possible ways with arange and array but I'm unable to get solution. Please help me out

Answer (score 1):

This passed all test cases:

```
x = np.arange(n, dtype=int).reshape(n_dim, n_row, n_col)
b = np.array([True, False], dtype="bool", ndmin=n_dim).reshape(2,)
print(x[b])
print(x[b, :, 1:3])
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following code for `x` array using `np.arrange`:

```
x = np.arange(n, dtype=int).reshape(n_dim, n_row, n_col)
```

it will work:

```
[[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
  [ 5  6  7  8  9]
  [10 11 12 13 14]]]
[[[ 1  2]
  [ 6  7]
  [11 12]]]
```

Comment: @JohnW welcome to SO. If any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. Thank you.